# Not found view doesn't work on Pyramid using traversal

Tags: pyramid

I'm using **Pyramid (1.5.7)** + **traversal** and following the [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html) I've tried all possible ways to get the "**Not found exception view**" working.

```
from pyramid.view import notfound_view_config,forbidden_view_config, view_config


@notfound_view_config(renderer="error/not_found.jinja2")
def not_found_view(request):
    request.response.status = 404
    return {}

@forbidden_view_config(renderer="error/forbidden.jinja2")
def forbidden_view(request):
    return {}
```

Using contexts:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPForbidden, HTTPUnauthorized


@view_config(context=HTTPNotFound, renderer="error/not_found.jinja2")
def not_found_view(request):
    request.response.status = 404
    return {}

@view_config(context=HTTPForbidden, renderer="error/forbidden.jinja2")
def forbidden_view(request):
    return {}
```

I'm using the [Scan](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html#term-scan) mode, but I've tried also adding a custom function to the configuration:

```
def main(globals, **settings):
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_notfound_view(notfound)
```

Not luck either, all time getting the following unhandled exception:

```
raise HTTPNotFound(msg)
pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound: /example-url
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more how it is not working? It is not running not found view Python code when it should? Have you put breakpoints inside the view function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch... My bad! I was using a tween which was preventing Pyramid to load the Exceptions:

```
def predispatch_factory(handler, registry):
    # one-time configuration code goes here

    def predispatch(request):
        # code to be executed for each request before
        # the actual application code goes here

        response = handler(request)

        # code to be executed for each request after
        # the actual application code goes here

        return response

    return predispatch
```

Still I don't know why but after removing this tween all seems to work as expected.